# Make a character vector a numeric vector in R?

Tags: r, vector

I have created a character vector using paste, for example:

```
y <- paste("a=1,b=2,c=3")
```

If I try to combine it:

```
x <- c(y)
```

I get:

```
[1] "a=1,b=2,c=3"
```

I would like to get the same as if I did:

```
c(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

which gives:

```
a b c   
1 2 3
```

Sorry if this is too basic, I am new to R (and the site). Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to build R code using strings? That's not really a great idea. Technically you could build R code and `eval()` it, bit if you're new to R that's not a path you should start off heading down. Where is this input coming from?

Comment: Your `y` and `x` are the same - the `c()` and `paste()` make no difference as `"Hello world"` and `paste("Hello world")` and `c("Hello world")` are all equivalent when you only have one single string. Are you looking for something like: `setNames(c(1:3),c("a","b","c"))` ?

Comment: As @MrFlick  says, using `eval()` so that R functions like a text replacement language to join `"c("` `"a=1,b=2,c=3"` and `")"` together as `c(a=1,b=2,c=3)` is really not appropriate or something one should be using as a starting point for R. Having said that, it can be done - `eval(parse(text=paste("c(",y,")")))` for instance. You almost certainly want to reconsider why you're doing this and potentially consider what data you have, and where you want to end up, and how this can be achieved **without** using `eval(parse(...))`

Comment: @MrFlick, I am trying to build code using strings. The input comes from the output (`summary()`) of a statistical model. Based on the values and variables from the model, I have to create an equation and enter it as a vector (like: `c(a=1,b=2,c=3)`, but more complicated). Rather than doing it by hand, I was trying to automate it. I am using paste to extract values and variable names from the output to put them in the equation and ended up with this issue. I now see that this might not be the best way to do it, but is what I could do. Your suggestion works. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @thelatemail, your suggestion with `eval()` works. I will consider other ways of doing this as I now see that it is not the best way, but is what I could do. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @san - you may also want to take a look at `coef()` and `predict()`, which respectively return the coefficients of a statistical model, or compute new values on the basis of a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if this is what your really want, but since you asked, here it is. This is not considered good practice, but perhaps you have a use case that would make it useful.

```
> eval( parse(text=paste("c(", y, ")" ) ) )
a b c 
1 2 3
```

The answedr fron Nader hints at what appears to be a missunderstanding about constructing R character variables. The `paste` functions seems entirely superfluous for building `y`: Just doing this is equivalent:

```
y <- "a=1,b=2,c=3"
```

Answer (score 2):

Is not clear what you want, but one option:

```
sepstr<-function(list,sep=",")unlist(strsplit(list, sep, fixed = TRUE))

d=sapply(sepstr(y),sepstr, sep="=")
x=as.numeric(d[2,])
names(x)=d[1,]
x
```

Or as @thelatemail suggested:

```
x2=setNames(as.numeric(d[2,]),d[1,])
x2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y <- c("a=1,b=2,c=3")

list <- lapply(strsplit(y , ","), function(x){
  strsplit(x , "=")
})

rapply(list, function(x){
  setNames(x[2] , x[1])
})

# a   b   c 
#"1" "2" "3"
```